# Determine if string is any integer, - is optional and if its a leading 0 it can only be 0?

Tags: java, regex, string, int

I want to determine if a string is any viable number, I have though made so many conditional statements it's not viable.
The number can start with "-" (optional), if it has a leading 0 it can only contain a 0 (still "-" is optional).

Some examples:

123 = true

-123 = true

-0 = true

-00 = false

12+4 = false

I have used .matches but I can't seem to figure out how to put it in as few of conditions as possible.

Comment: I read through some of the comments but didn't find a satisfying answer.

Comment: What, precisely, were you expecting? What constitutes a "satisfying" answer?

Comment: What about string representations of float or double type values?

Comment: It didn't cover the aspect if the string has a leading zero and more zeros beyond that.

Comment: Nevermind I am the one in the wrong, this question is a duplicate.